# FileNotFoundException when trying to add an Attachment to Outlook Mailitem in C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook-addin

I am trying to send a mail on Outlook 2013 startup programmatically that has programmatically added attachments. Then the programm takes these attachments and creates a Password-locked Zip File and also adds this File as attachment. My Problem is, that I keep getting an

```
"System.IO.FileNotFoundException"
```

when executing

```
mail.Attachments.Add(pathToAttachment1);
```

I thought the path might not exist, but I can add this Path to a new zip-directory (using the same String), so it seems to be a Problem with the

```
Attachments.Add(Object)-Method.
```

MSDN says it is totally fine to give it a Pathname as String. In VBA it even worked, but in c# not (for whatever reason). Does somebody have an idea what i am doing wrong?

The Code i want to execute:

```
String pathToAttachment1 = @"C:\Testfile.txt";

//create a new ZipFile
ZipFile zipAttachment = new ZipFile("EncodedAttachments.zip");
zipAttachment.Password = "1234";

//Create a new MailItem 
Outlook.MailItem mail  = Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem); 

//set Receiver, Body and Subject for the MailItem
mail.To = "foo";
mail.Body = "This is the body.";
mail.Subject = "This is the Subject.";

//This is working:
zipAttachment.AddFile(pathToAttachment1);

//This is the line where the Exception is thrown:
mail.Attachments.Add(pathToAttachment1);
```

This code is called in the Startup-Method handling the Outlook Startup Event. Does anyone have an idea what i might do wrong or could change to make it work?

Comment: Try adding a button in Addin. Let the Addin load completely. Now on button_click event handler do these operation of adding attachments.

Comment: Is that your actual code? pathToAttachment1 declaration will not compile.

Comment: Sorry i missed that  "  when shortening that file declaration :D I don't know what problem visual studio had, restared the pc and changed the file delcaration from @"C:\..." to "C:\\.....", now it works for me - thanks for your answers :)